# MSAL/Angular - Intermittently token seems to go stale and msal constructs incorrect url for authentication

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular7 app using msal 0.1.2. Intermittently a user is unable to access anything requiring authentication and when you look in developer tools network tab you can see a GET request to get authentication to https://login.microsoftonline.com/[a GUID]/oauth2/v2.0/undefined which returns a 404 whenever the user clicks on a link to content requiring authentication. This seems to happen when a user has not accessed the website since the previous day.
This error occurs in the msal code itself.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue, and it turned out that 3rd party cookies were getting blocked. The cookies for `login.microsoftonline.com` were getting blocked by the browser, resulting in the odd authorize url.

Enabling 3rd party cookies resolved the issue!

The MSAL Team says this is an issue with login.microsoftonline.com, not with MSAL itself. (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/970)

We were using MSAL v0.1.4